# Actual power consumption of a smartphone charger

Tags: battery-charging, electricity, power-consumption

When I search on the Internet "How much power does a smartphone charger consume?" it shows "3-7W". I know Power = Voltage x Current. Based on the equation and the input ratings (110-240V, 0.5A) on my smartphone charger if I calculate, the power consumption equals 220V x 0.5A = 110W. Can someone explain this? Note that the voltage in India is 220V, alternating at 50Hz per second.

Comment: 0.5 A input rating is the absolute maximum input current. Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262975/switching-power-supply-why-is-the-primary-current-rating-1a-off-when-calculatin?r=SearchResults

Comment: Just a note: "*50Hz per second*" isn't correct. The hertz unit is cycles per second so "50 Hz per second" means 50 cycles per second per second (which would be a rate of change of frequency). It's just "50 Hz".

Answer (score 0):

Your charger is about 80-90% efficient, so if you're charging at 10W, it's probably consuming 11 or 12 watts.

You could get an AC power meter to measure power consumption exactly.